# batch file multiple results to seperate variables

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have a .exe that prints the results of multiple devices connected to the PC. Each item is on a separate line, however, depending on what's connected the results can 1 to many devices.

how do i set each one to a separate variable?

```
testapp.exe -l
340e42e15fc02fb99e7caf66565d3c881081390c
4e8e93bd2a401c34e3d0d257de07af5d624521c6
```

the below will only work when the result is one device

```
for /f "tokens=1 " %%a in ('testapp.exe') do set DEVICE1=%%a
```

ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use an [array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10166386/arrays-linked-lists-and-other-data-structures-in-cmd-exe-batch-script/10167990#10167990) to store each result in each array element:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set n=0
for /F %%a in ('testapp.exe -l') do (
   set /A n+=1
   set "device[!n!]=%%a"
)

echo The devices are:
for /L %%i in (1,1,%n%) do echo %%i- !device[%%i]!
```

Comment: Thanks, what %varible% do i use with the results? 
    echo %device% | echo %device1% | ETC

Comment: If `device` is the name of the array, then `%device[1]%` is the first element, `%device[2]%` is the second one, etc. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Array_data_structure#One-dimensional_arrays), or [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_programming_languages_(array)#Indexing), or the description at the array link given above...

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexapansion
set i=0
for /f %%a in ('testapp.exe -l') do (
  set /a i+=1
  set device!i!=%%a
)
echo %i% devices:
set device
```